# python - double bars are cut out of chart area

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a double bar graph and line graph on the same chart. For the first and last x-tick, only one bar is visible in the chart. All the x-ticks in the middle have double bars (as I would like). [image: image here]

this is the code I am using:

```
for h in range(0,len(x)):   # len(x) is > 4000
    if h > 0 :
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)   
        ax1.set_xlim([-1,13])          
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        df2[['A','B']].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, figsize=(15, 10), legend=False)
        df2[['C']].plot(style='r-', ax=ax2, figsize=(15, 10), marker='o',legend=False)

        ax1.set_xlabel("x-label", fontsize=15)
        ax1.set_ylabel("y-label 1", fontsize=15)
        ax2.set_ylabel("y-label 2", fontsize=15)

        # h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        # h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.grid()
        fig.savefig('xyz.png')
        plt.close()
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the xlimits after creating the plot.

```
for h in range(0,len(x)):   # len(x) is > 4000
    if h > 0 :          
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()   
        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        df2[['A','B']].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, figsize=(15, 10), legend=False)
        df2[['C']].plot(style='r-', ax=ax2, figsize=(15, 10), marker='o',legend=False)

        ax1.set_xlabel("x-label", fontsize=15)
        ax1.set_ylabel("y-label 1", fontsize=15)
        ax2.set_ylabel("y-label 2", fontsize=15)

        ax1.set_xlim((-1,13))  # <-----   here

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.grid()
        fig.savefig('xyz.png')
        plt.close()
```

Comment: if do this, only the first plot shows line graph. all others show only bar graphs

Comment: can you be clearer please? thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Obviously the code does not give the desired result. In order to find out the reason, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue, otherwise one cannot test it.

Comment: A,B,C are df with 30 random numbers

Answer (score 1):

Change the x limits and both should appear:

```
plt.xlim(-1,13)
```

Comment: pls see edit. this is part of a for loop. if i set `plt.xlim (-1,13)` then only the firs plot shows line graph. all others don't. I didnt mention this sooner because i didnt think it would matter

Comment: in that case you can set the limits for each subplot (in the for loop)

Comment: i edited the code to include limits in the loop. that didnt make any difference @Cary Shindell

Comment: Did you do it at the very beginning of the loop, before creating the bars?

Comment: yes, that gives me bars in only first graph. other bars have only the line graph :(

Comment: try doing `ax1.xlim(-1,13)`, etc.

Comment: i tried `ax1.set_xlim(-1,13)` and got `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'xlim'`

Comment: try `ax1.set_xlim([-1,13])` instead

Comment: that doesnt change anything :(

Comment: maybe the subplots are set up wrong. Try doing `ax1 = plt.subplot(211)` instead of `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()`

Comment: Try defining the x limits after creating the plots

Comment: Also you have some weird statements at the end. Try getting rid of the tight layout, grid, and maybe replace `.close()` with `.show()`

Comment: i tried both these things and the output is still the same @Cary Shindell

Comment: You're getting the error, or just the bars not showing up?

Comment: just the bars not showing up. line graphs plot in all charts

Comment: did the x limits change? also did you try without the tight layout?

Comment: without tight layout, the x-label gets cut off.  x limits dont change.

Comment: Well Im at a loss then. Try commenting out lines and going down to just an empty plot until you can get the x limits working, then go from there